# Bulk select into FROM Information_schema.Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to copy records from a bunch of tables into one table. I run through the tables dynamically. This works OK for the first encountered table. However, when it gets to the next variable table, it reports the destination table is already existing:

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max) = ''

SELECT @SQL = @SQL + 'select Datum, Tijd, Scanner into my_destination_table from '+ TABLE_NAME +' where tijd > 12 '
FROM Information_schema.Tables
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'tbl_%_Tijden'
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;


Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line 1
There is already an object named 'my_destination_table' in the database.
```

I just need it to keep filling my_destination_table with the records found.

Any suggestions?

thx,
James

@Giorgos, your solution seems to be working OK. I have tweaked it a liitle bit, and it does work. What I don't understand is why the results are doubled? This is the SQL:

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max) = ''
declare @t nvarchar(max) = '';

select @t = min(TABLE_NAME) from Information_schema.Tables 
where TABLE_NAME > @t and TABLE_NAME like 'tbl_%_Tijden';
delete from tblfouttijden;
while @t is not null
begin
    set @SQL = 'insert into tblfouttijden (Projectnr, Datum, Start, Einde, Tijd, TijdTijd, Scanner, StartID, EindID, Naam) select Projectnr, Datum, Start, Einde, Tijd, TijdTijd, Scanner, StartID, EindID, Naam from '+ @t +' where tijd > 12 ';
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
-- Move to the next table, if one exists:
select @t = min(TABLE_NAME) from Information_schema.Tables WHERE TABLE_NAME > @t and TABLE_NAME LIKE 'tbl_%_Tijden';
   end
```

Comment: Do you have `Create table` before this statement?

Comment: After the first `select into` the table `my_destination_table` has been created, so the next statements must use the `insert into my_destination_table` format.

Comment: No, I do not have the Create Table statement.

Comment: Giorgos, that's my question exactly. How do I do that?

Comment: Let me work on it for a while!

Comment: You must have the table named "my_destination_table", you can try : select * from my_destination_table

Comment: I added a new answer, I am deleting the other one as I consider this to be better overall (and it does not have the duplicates issue).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will avoid duplicates:

```
create table tblfouttijden (Datum varchar(10), Tijd int, Scanner varchar(20)
           , ... ) ;

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max) = '';
declare @t nvarchar(max) = '';

select @t = min(TABLE_NAME) from Information_schema.Tables WHERE TABLE_NAME > @t and TABLE_NAME LIKE 'tbl_%_Tijden';

set @SQL = 'select Projectnr, Datum, Start, Einde, Tijd, TijdTijd, Scanner, StartID, EindID, Naam from '
          + @t +' where tijd > 12 ';

while @t is not null
begin
    select @t = min(TABLE_NAME) from Information_schema.Tables WHERE TABLE_NAME > @t and TABLE_NAME LIKE 'tbl_%_Tijden';
    if @t is not null
        set @SQL = @SQL + 'union select Projectnr, Datum, Start, Einde, Tijd, TijdTijd, Scanner, StartID, EindID, Naam from '
              + @t +' where tijd > 12 ';
end

set @SQL = 'insert into tblfouttijden (Projectnr, Datum, Start, Einde, Tijd, TijdTijd, Scanner, StartID, EindID, Naam) ' 
        + @SQL;

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Comment: Thanks, Giorgos. Great answer!